# Drupal updating form fields on file upload

Tags: php, drupal

I am trying to update form fields based on an uploaded file.  I'm using `hook_form_alter()` to perform these updates, and I have found that I can change the `default_value` of a field when the webpage is first loaded.  However, the same thing does not work when `hook_form_alter()` is called as a result of a file being uploaded.  For instance,

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

   // I can change the default value here
   $form['field_myfield']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = "Some Value";

   // Check to see if the upload button has been pressed
   if (array_key_exists('clicked_button', $form_state))){
       $trigger = $form_state['clicked_button']['#value'];

       if($trigger == 'Upload'){

           // Try to change the default value here.  The value is changed in $form, 
           // but the field is not updated on the website.  
           $form['field_myfield']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = "New Value";
       }
   }

}
```

Do I need to perform some sort of refresh? I briefly looked at AHAH, is this something I need to use?  I am new to Drupal and I apologize in advance if there is something fundamentally wrong with my terminology and/or approach.

Any help is greatly appreciated.